# Do we need to use many-to-one if we have already one-to-many?

Tags: sql, jpa, jakarta-ee, data-structures

I am learning java EE and spring. I want to create a blog system, with user,blog,comment entities.  A user can have many blog, a blog can have many comment.
My question is, once i created one-to-many realtionship to the user-blog, do i have to use many-to-one backwards as well? I checked a few example and i saw both solution. When do we have to use each?

Comment: That depends if your relation is UNIdirectional or BIdirectional ...

Comment: No you can do it either way. Entirely depends if, in your in-memory model you have an instance of a blog, you want to be able to do blog.getUser();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's conventient to have `@ManyToOne` backlink from a "child" to a "parent" entity because then you can specify which property of your "child" entity in a `@OneToMany` relationship is the property holding the information to which "parent" entity your "child" entity belongs (via `mappedBy`-field) - as on database-level the information to which "parent" entity your "child" entity belongs is represented with a foreign key in the "child" entity (to keep attributes atomic) in contrast to the object "world" where your "parent" entity would have a list of "children".